# Need help to explain "set a-rattling the sabers of"

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis

> Austin had distanced himself and his colonists from American filibusters in dramatic and determined fashion, but the sad escapade set a-rattling
>   the sabers of many a newspaper editor in the United States and many a political firebrand in Mexico.

I can understand the sentence, but why the author uses *set a-rattling the sabers of*. I've googled and searched it in corpora, yet nothing comes up. Is anyone know similar sentences or something about it?

Comment: Look up "sabre-rattling" or "saber rattling". This is a relatively common figure of speech.

Comment: Also, there, **to set** means to cause the sabers to rattle

Comment: Since we're talking about newspaper editors and it's the year 2020: *triggered* - that's what it means.

Answer (score 17):

It looks like a combination of two standard phrase forms:

1. *set a-***verb**, which means simply to start the operation of the verb.

   For example, to *set a-flutter* is to *start {something} fluttering*.
   This form often seems to diminish or trivialise the verb.
2. *saber rattling* (or *sabre rattling*), which means to deliberately telegraph a threat, or otherwise communicate a threatening posture

So, while you can find plenty of examples of both in isolation, this particular combination may be original.

Comment: It should be noted that using "a-" in this sense is fairly common but informal.

Comment: Yes, Useless and Hot Licks are right.  In addition, however, the use of this particular expression is inept.  'Sabre rattling' is, as Useless says, a kind of threat.  A swordsman, instead of taking his sabre out and striking a blow, leaves it in its sheath and rattles it.  What the author seems to be saying is (to continue the metaphor) is that a small army of journalists not just rattling their sabres but actually drawing them out of the scabbards and striking.

Comment: @Tuffy Journalists can only rattle sabers; drawing the sabers requires soldiers.

Comment: @Acccumulation Well, not really.  Sabre-rattling is a graphic way to describe threatening behaviour.  But the one thing the press cannot do is threaten, since the only threat it can make is of adverse publicity.

Comment: I wouldn't say "threat" as much as belligerent posing. For a newspaper, I'd say that saber rattling would be articles about a hypothetical war, patriotic calls to arms, maybe lampooning of the target country, its politics or politicians, etc - but not threats per se.

Comment: @Tuffy it gave me the image of swashbuckling pirate films where they rattle their sabres at each other in a mock fight.

Comment: There is a hyphenated noun ‘sabre-rattling’, (British English) defined in Merriam Webster as:  “overtly and often exaggeratedly threatening actions or statements (such as verbal threats or ostentatious displays of military power) that are meant to intimidate an enemy by suggesting possible use of force.”

Comment: @Acccumulation not so: [*The pen is mightier than the sword*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_pen_is_mightier_than_the_sword).

Answer (score 5):

*Sabre-rattling* (or *saber* in American English) is an idiom with the sense of 'rattling one's sword in its scabbard as though threatening to draw it' 
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sabre-rattling

Here, the writer has turned the phrase round. The meaning seems to be 'made them behave in a threatening manner' rather than a reference to actual military action.

Comment: I am fairly certain it is an idiom from rattling **the scabbard** of the saber against something, especially the floor - borrowed from Spanish: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saber_noise

Comment: @StianYttervik I didn't know that - I just guessed the literal meaning from the figurative one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A phrase with a similar meaning that might be used today would be:

> Austin had distanced himself and his colonists from American
>   filibusters in dramatic and determined fashion, but the sad escapade
>   **raised the hackles** of many a newspaper editor in the United
>   States and many a political firebrand in Mexico.